# how can i use patterns like *, ? , [ ]in the query of database in jsp?

Tags: mysql, jsp, jsp-tags

i facing problem while writing database query in jsp that uses a string patterns.
example : i want to know whether a table exists or not in database, the table name can start with any name but ends with " session". eg : guru_session, hellosession, etc.

how can write that query ?

```
  here is my code in jsp :
  DatabaseMetaData md = con.getMetaData();
  ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "table_name_here", null);
```

i tried using "*session" to check a table name "guru_session" exists or not .
but its not working. give me some help here.

Comment: No way you cannot access a table without having known the table name. Are you by any chance trying to hack into the Database and do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing, javascript and java are different languages. In your case javascript works in a client browser, when java runs on a server.

There is a way to interact between client and server via javascript asynchronously in background. Your task appears a bit strange, and in my experience when a developer needs to make non-elegant decisions upon development process, then there's something wrong with the whole application structure. It could be useful to reconsider the architecture of your solution.

It depends on a database platform, but table names are stored in system tables. Check system tables for your particular RDBMS platform, and query these system table(s) to get information you need. You can do it asynchronously in background via ajax calls to a servlet on the server and act accordingly on the client's browser.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a query like that:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM information_schema.tables 
 WHERE table_name LIKE '%session';
```

I think that this approach can help you.